# How To: Install Proteus from Humble Indie Bundle Depends: proteus (= 1.1-0ubuntu3)

Tags: games, dependencies, metapackages

After redeeming my software center key to download Proteus from the new Humble Indie Bundle #8, this error appears:

```
proteus-meta: Depends: proteus (= 1.1-0ubuntu3) but 1.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

I have tried:

-Purging a few questionable  repositories (pulseaudiodev, markjtully, xorg-edgers, nae-team)

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge 1.1-0ubuntu2
sudo apt-get install 1.1-0ubuntu3
```

--UPDATE 05/28/13--
It now seems that the real culprit is "libdgiplus," which I cannot figure out how to install from here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgdiplus/2.10-3ubuntu1

```
Running "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" in a folder only containing the Proteus .deb file returns:
Selecting previously unselected package proteus.
(Reading database ... 343081 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking proteus (from proteus_1.1-0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of proteus:
 proteus depends on libgdiplus; however:
  Package libgdiplus is not installed.

dpkg: error processing proteus (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
proteus
```

Comment: Uninstall proteus, install the library, reinstall proteus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 64-bit, the libgdiplus:i386 conflicts with libgdiplus, and removing that tries to uninstall a whole pile of stuff you may want, like banshee.

If you're not, then you can open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get -f install` and it'll fix up the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

But it also removes proteus ...

> Blockquote
>   run sudo apt-get -f install and it'll fix up the dependencies.